# Prestashop redirection after registration

Tags: prestashop

I made a `CustomerRedirection` **Module** which is very simple. Whenever a user register I want him to be redirected to a template named `validation` which is just a page saying Successfully registered.

The validation page is located at `127.0.0.1/content/6-validation`

Here is the code :

```
public function hookActionCustomerAccountAdd()
{
    Tools::redirectLink(__PS_BASE_URI__.'content/6-validation');
}
```

After the registration I'm redirect to the registration page once again.

Answer (score 0):

Tools::redirectLink is expecting a path already containing PS_BASE_URI

I usually prefer using Tools::redirect instead, that can parse both external and internal URLs.

So you can either use :

```
Tools::redirect('https://full-url-here')
```

or

```
Tools::redirect('index.php?id_cms=6&controller=cms');
```

That will redirect to the same controller in a non-rewrited fashion.

Comment: I've tried with the localhost `Tools::redirect('localhost/content/6-validation');` but I still get redirected to the empty registration form

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I clarified my answer a little better.... let me know !